# Ansible: user is not authenticating to network share

Tags: powershell, ansible, robocopy

I'm having difficulty transferring files from a network share to a disk on the local server, via a remote connection.
I am logging into the server: SERVER02, however, permission denied appears, using Wireshark collections on SERVER01, I found that user credentials and passwords are not arriving.
It's strange because doing the local robocopy command in PowerShell works correctly.
Also, I've used Ansible modules and they didn't work, this module ansible.windows.win_powershell was the one that gave me the most information.
Below is the code that is executed and its output:

```
- name: Copy files from network share folder to Windows server
  hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_user: "{{ vm_user }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ vm_pass }}"
    ansible_port: 5985
    ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

  tasks:
    - name: Copia arquivos
      ansible.windows.win_powershell: 
        script: |
          $Username = "{{ vm_user }}"
          $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "{{ vm_pass }}" -AsPlainText -Force
          $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword
          Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "{{ host_group }}" -Credential $Credential
          robocopy \\SERVER01\I$\APP\MONITOR\ \\SERVER02\I$\JOBS\ /COPYALL /MT /E /b /W:5 /R:5
```

Output execution:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : terca-feira, 10 de outubro de 2023 10:14:27
   Source = \\SERVER01\I$\APP\MONITOR\
     Dest : \\SERVER02\I$\JOBS\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPYALL /B /MT:8 /R:5 /W:5

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NOTE : Security may not be copied - Source might not support persistent ACLs.

2023/10/10 10:14:27 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Accessing Source Directory \\SERVER01\I$\APP\MONITOR\
Access is denied.
```

Copy performed between directories successfully with ansible.

Comment: It’s *probably* because when you try to access the network share from inside a Powershell remoting session you're trying to do a “double-hop” (i.E use PowerShell remoting on Server A to connect to Server B, and then from Server B try to connect to a network share on Server C) but the credentials you used to open the remoting session from Setver A to Server B can’t be re-used by Server B to connect to Server C. See this for more details, and options to resolve… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: The reason it works *locally* is because you’re only doing one hop from an interactive session on Server B to the network share on Server C, and you’re using your logged-in credentials to authenticate with the network share.